# Low Peer Count For a light ethereum node

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, mastering-ethereum, ethernodes

I am running a Light node via Geth in a Debian OS . i am getting 1/2 max peers and for many hours of the day with 0 peers . what is the solution ? how to get atleast one peer everytime ?

Comment: What's your Geth command line to launch the node ?

Comment: You are on the mainnet ?